# How to add to Spring ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring

in my application i need to add contents of of a couple of spring config files based on some business logic. i can get the context using an applicationContextAware class. ut my question is regarding how i can add "Resource"s to the context. i mean loading the resources and adding them to the Context at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do? The bean wiring will have already taken place so you won't be able to inject those new properties...

Comment: yes. of course spring should rewire them.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new ApplicationContext based on your resources and then set the existing one as parent context.

In case of a web-app you will need to set the new context to the context variable where spring stores its context.

Comment: thanks. just a couple of questions: 1. how can i set the parent Context? 2. it is a web app, it is created with ContextLoaderListener, which Context variable spring uses? can you give a line or 2 of code?

Comment: The listener is a good starting point to find out :)

It uses the ContextLoader.initWebapplicationcontext(ServletContext) ro start a spring context. There the work you need to do is some sort of the same.

The variable is: WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE

In ContextLoader.createWebApplicationcontext(Servletcontext,ApplicationContext) is shown how its created. WebApplicationContext has a setParent() method. That is the easy part :)

Comment: actually it doesn't seem that webappcontext has a public setParent() :) that is the hard part maybe. and maybe i am wrong, but i don't think you can get the functionality by copy-pasting the spring code itself :) there should be some exposed interface or ,,, to do that.

Comment: well we once created an installer for a web-app that works this way. Spring does not do some magic stuff to create a context, this can be done manually any time.
In ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext there is:
ConfigurableWebApplicationContext wac =
    (ConfigurableWebApplicationContext) BeanUtils.instantiateClass(contextClass);

that is the one I would use.